# PyAutoGui and PyScreeze

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, pyautogui

I have coded a simple Osu! bot, but it doesnt work. I get no error until i open (fullscreen) osu. I have tried running it from cmd with administrator, but it just wont work. I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Kris/PycharmProjects/OsuBot/venv/drums.py", line 7, in <module>
    if pyautogui.pixel(609, 440)[0] == 235:
  File "C:\Users\Kris\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\pyscreeze\__init__.py", line 584, in pixel
    return (r, g, b)
  File "C:\Users\Kris\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\contextlib.py", line 120, in __exit__
    next(self.gen)
  File "C:\Users\Kris\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\pyscreeze\__init__.py", line 113, in __win32_openDC
    raise WindowsError("windll.user32.ReleaseDC failed : return 0")
OSError: windll.user32.ReleaseDC failed : return 0

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I get the error while running from IDLE, cmd and PyCharm.

Here is my code:

```
import pyautogui
import keyboard
import time

while 1:
    if pyautogui.pixel(609, 440)[0] == 235:
        keyboard.press('x')
        time.sleep(0.1)
        keyboard.release('x')
    if pyautogui.pixel(609, 440)[0] == 67:
        keyboard.press('z')
        time.sleep(0.1)
        keyboard.release('z')
    time.sleep(0.01)

# X:  609 Y:  440 RGB: ( 32,  99, 222)
# RED = X: 1534 Y:  485 RGB: (235,  69,  44)
# BLUE = X: 1138 Y:  459 RGB: ( 67, 142, 172)
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like `pyautogui` has some issues with pixel indetification as I've also tried out `pyautogui.pixel()` and I seem to be getting the same `OSError: windll.user32.ReleaseDC failed : return 0` however for some reason it works half the time and I get the code to function properly. Not sure why though, I'm not doing anything except re-running the program several times in a row until it works.

You could try the `pillow` library using `pip install pillow` which has a `getpixel()` function. You'd have to take a screenshot first but thankfully `pyautogui` has that covered:

```
from PIL import Image
import pyautogui as py

py.screenshot('file.png')

img = Image.open('file.png')
print(img.getpixel((180, 90)))
```

I see you're also using the `keyboard` library, but honestly you could just use `pyautogui` for that and then you wouldn't need to import an extra library.

**FINAL CODE**

```
import time
from PIL import Image
import pyautogui as py

while 1:

    py.screenshot('file.png')
    img = Image.open('file.png')
    
    if img.getpixel((609, 440))[0] == 235:
        py.press('x')
    if img.getpixel((609, 440))[0] == 67:
        py.press('z')
    time.sleep(1)
```